# How to unlock Firefox with a password to get access to all my services like Facebook?

Tags: firefox

I want a Firefox setting like whenever I open Firefox, It should act like it doesn't remember anything, no browsing history, no cookies, no passwords for any site.

But as soon as I provide one password to Firefox, it should treat like "My Firefox" and sign in all the site for me like Facebook, GMail and others. In short I don't want to sign in all sites time and again, and at the same time I don't want Firefox to remember history.

Is there any setting in Firefox?

Comment: Run Firefox in a password-protected, encrypted virtual machine (e.g. in VirtualBox). That will protect your browsing history and cookies. Signing into sites - use a password manager browser plugin.

Comment: (I've voted to put on hold as off-topic - it should be on _SuperUser_ I think).